# Replacing Bathroom Switch with Timer Switch Not Working

Tags: bathroom, switch, replacement, timer

I have two switches in the bathroom, one that controls a light(left switch) and one that turns on the fan(right switch). I know there is an extra connection between the left light switch and the main line coming in and can fix that later. The picture of how it works in original form with the older switches each independently control their switches. When I added the timer switch to the right fan switch, turning on the left light switch also turned on the fan but none of the buttons on the timer switch worked. Once the power is returned it is supposed to take about a minute to charge up the timer switch but even after that time there is no response with the timer switch. I have tried different ways to wire the two but not able to get the timer to work.[image]

I tried the suggestion that the wire for the left switch may be the main power. When I put the power back on the left switch works as it should but the right timer switch went on but has no control through the timer switch buttons. Picture showing this included.[image]

Comment: It sounds like the wire you thought was the incoming hot is actually going off to the fan instead

Comment: The picture on the left allows the two things work independently, which is how it was essentially when I opened it up. Hooking the timer the same way the old right switch was does not make the timer work but makes it so the left switch turn both things on.

Comment: 1 - Make/model of the timer switch? 2 - The middle cable looks like it has black for incoming hot and white *just hanging there, not capped, not connected to anything*, which is very strange (to me at least). 3 - The other wires (what appear to be switched hots) are leaving the box individually. Usually they would be paired with their partner neutrals unless they are switch loops, and then they would be paired with their partner hots. A lot of this just doesn't look right.

Comment: The timer switch is GE Push Button Countdown Timer GE5340-71L3 Cat No. 15318. When I first opened it up the only wires connected were the three black wires, the white one was not connected to anything.